# Fixed Header in Wordpress + Static Lines

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, fixed

I'm creating [this site](http://abrushwithgrace.com) using the dazzling theme and everything seems to work fine except the header.

Have added these code lines to my css and it works fine for the homepage as you can see.

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
width: 100%;
```

However, when you visit any other page or blog post, the header is messed up. Can you please provide a solution.

Another problem is, on the home page carousal, I need to add a few more lines to the blog excerpt (Art brings faith to life. This blog....). Can it be done via CSS?

Solved both the problems:

1. Adding a single line top:0; did the trick. Thanks to the community for helping out.
2. It seems, the problem was with the default WP excerpt which is 55. Used a single function in the functions.php file which did the trick. Have mentioned it below if it might be a help for others.

   ```
   /* New excerpt length of 120 words*/
   function my_excerpt_length($length) {
   return 70;
   }
   add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');
   ```

You can change the 70 to anything you like :)

Comment: can youprovide a little fiddle, you can however set a margin top on the element beneath (e.g "Artists")

Comment: Didn't get your point. Can you please explain a bit? Sorry, new to this.

Comment: O, can you provide a little snippet (some isoloated code from your project) , see this: https://jsfiddle.net put your css and html here and w'll try to fix your problem

Comment: @eugensunic wants you to create a [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you read the [help] it will help you ask questions and get better answers.

Comment: @Liam... Understood. I will go through the post and try to provide a better overview of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem The menu having the problem because you set margin-top for your content id.

Keep this as it is if you need to have, make change in you css

style.css line 612

you have to

```
.navbar.navbar-default
{
leave other css as it is and change only
position: fixed;
top: 0; /* This one you miss*/
and remove margin
}
```

For second thing you can increase the width or give height to your blog excerpt div.
 in flexslider.css at line 98

Comment: Thanks! The header problem is solved. However, the second problem still persists. Even if I increase the width or the height of the excerpt box, the amount of text it shows is set fixed.

Answer (score 0):

just add top:0 in this css rule .navbar.navbar-default

.

```
navbar.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder. I could solve the header problem. Much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome Then please mark this as correct answer so it will help others

Comment: I am looking for an answer to my second problem as well before I can mark. Thanks!